# Devkit function in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, devkit

I am new to rubyonrails. Any one can explain me please what is devkit and what is the function of devkit in RoR. How we use this. Any can please..

Comment: Please go through http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/. It may help you.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i did not get any thing from this site. Why we need to install this. can you explain me